# SQL Server : wrong index is used when filter value exceeds the index histogram range

Tags: sql-server, database, histogram, query-performance

We have a very large table, where every day 1-2 million rows are being added to the table.

In this query:

```
SELECT jobid, exitstatus 
FROM jobsData 
WHERE finishtime >= {ts '2012-10-04 03:19:26'} AND task = 't1_345345_454' 
GROUP BY jobid, exitstatus
```

Indexes exists for both `Task` and `FinishTime`.

We expected that the `task` index will be used since it has much fewer rows. The problem that we see is that SQL Server creates a bad query execution plan which uses the `FinishTime` index instead of the task, and the query takes very long time.

This happens when the finish time value is outside the `FinishTime` index histogram.

Statistics are updated every day / several hours, but there are still many cases where the queries are for recent values.

The question: we can see clearly in the estimated execution plan that the estimated number of rows for the `FinishTime` is `1` in this case, so the `FinishTime` index is selcted. Why SQL Server assumes that this is `1` if there is no data? Is there a way to tell it to use something more reasonable?

When we replace the date with a bit earlier one, statistics exists in the histogram and the estimated number of rows is ~7000

Comment: I'd just use a query hint in this case to force the plan you want.

Comment: The queries vary a lot, so it's hard to know which hint to use. How can we deal with the wrong estimation of expected rows for FinishtTime index? Why does the engine guesses it will be 1? Can't he take some average of other buckets?

Comment: @duduamar - How do you know the queries vary a lot? Do you work with the OP or something?

Comment: There are automatic tools which generates these queries where on each query the times are different. We also have traces of the executed queries, each query has a different time.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [Plan Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190417.aspx) to instruct the optimizer to use a specific query plan for you. This fits well for generated queries that you cannot modify to add hints.

Comment: This can be helpful - Thanks! Still, it'll require a lot of changes for us since the current queries have their values as part of the query text rather than parameters. Any idea why the estimated number of rows is "1" in these cases? it would make sense to set it to something closer to the existing histogram values or for e.g. an average over all values

Comment: Even if you specify values as scalars not as parameters plan guide can still work, because of [auto-parametrization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186219%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).